# Add a total row summation columns into a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe made up to multiple volume columns only and I want to create a total column called test which sits in the dataframe. The below code will work if I just set `test <- ...` but if I add `summary_transposed_no_time$` to the left, the code doesn't seem to add it to the dataframe.

I would also like to know how I could evolve this piece of code so that I could create test to be all columns minus column 1, and then later in the process create another test column (maybe called test2) which would be a summation of all columns minus column 2 - I can hard code the column positions but not the column names (as they can change in naming convention each time the code is run) so I haven't included them here

```
w <- ncol(summary_transposed_no_time)
summary_transposed_no_time$test <- apply(summary_transposed_no_time[,c(1:w)], 1, sum)
```

**Example of summary_transposed_no_time:**

```
postal_dist_a | postal_dist_b | postal_dist_c
------------- | ------------- | -------------
20            | 25            | 15
25            | 40            | 23
31            | 32            | 19
24            | 39            | 17
37            | 19            | 26
```

**Desired result columns within summary_transposed_no_time:**

```
postal_dist_a | postal_dist_b | postal_dist_c | test
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
20            | 25            | 15            | 60
25            | 40            | 23            | 88
31            | 32            | 19            | 82
24            | 39            | 17            | 80
37            | 19            | 26            | 82
```

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide a reprocucible example.
But if your question is really just about how to do rowsums, I would rather use the built in function rowSums. Your code would be :

```
set.seed(1)
# I recreate a table more or less like yours
summary_transposed_no_time=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol=5))
n=ncol(summary_transposed_no_time)

# Test that contains the rowsum
summary_transposed_no_time$test=rowSums(summary_transposed_no_time)

# test1 rowsum minus column 1
summary_transposed_no_time$testm1=rowSums(summary_transposed_no_time[,2:n])
# test2 rowsum minus column 2
summary_transposed_no_time$testm2=rowSums(summary_transposed_no_time[,c(1,3:n)])
#test_i minus column i
i=3
summary_transposed_no_time$testmi=rowSums(summary_transposed_no_time[,c(1:n)][,-i])

#check on first line :
sum(summary_transposed_no_time[1,1:n])==summary_transposed_no_time$test[1]
sum(summary_transposed_no_time[1,2:n])==summary_transposed_no_time$testm1[1]
sum(summary_transposed_no_time[1,c(1,3:n)])==summary_transposed_no_time$testm2[1]
sum(summary_transposed_no_time[1,c(1:2,4:n)])==summary_transposed_no_time$testmi[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Arault, I'm running the line you provided: summary_transposed_no_time$testm1 = rowSums(summary_transposed_no_time[,1:n]) with an ncol count and a print before and after the step. The number printed by ncols goes from 132 prior to creating testm1 to 133 after but I cannot find the column testm1. Not sure what I'm doing wrong? I ran the table you created and I can see testm1 within that?

Comment: That is strange, what happens when you do summary_transposed_no_time$testm1[1,1] ? Because if the number of columns changed it must have created something. Try colnames(summary_transposed_no_time) if it doesn't work to see the name of the colums. I see in your comment a small error, it's summary_transposed_no_time[,**2**:n], not summary_transposed_no_time[,**1**:n] in the function.

Comment: Thanks again, [1,1] and [,1:n] both result in testm1 showing up in the `colnames()` result  but not visibly when I open the frame. As a SAS developer I have made the assumption that the new field will be at the RHS of the frame, is this the case? having said that, I have viewed all columns and it's definitely not there?

Comment: Yes it should be the last column, if you use Rstudio with the view() function, maybe it doesn't appear due to a limit on the number of column displayed ?

Comment: Thanks Arault, the # test1 rowsum minus column 1 logic works perfectly and if I run a `[myvars]` I can see tesm1 so I think my issue was purely in what R displayed rather than what it created. The bit I can't seem to get to work is the #test_i minus column i logic - my frame has 132 numeric columns and I want to end up with 132 summations, each one being all other columns added minus that columns. Iv'e tried a `for (h in 1:ncol)` but can't get h to resolve to a variable name creation or the `[,-h]` logic: `summary_transposed_no_time$test_h = rowSums(summary_transposed_no_time[,c(1:n)][,-h])`

Answer (score 0):

I've found how to create a "total_" for every column within the df. total_1 is the sum of all columns minus column 1, total_2 the sum of all columns minus column 2 etc etc

```
n=ncol(summary_transposed_no_time)

for (h in 1:ncol(summary_transposed_no_time)) {

  summary_transposed_no_time[,paste0("total_",h)] <- rowSums(summary_transposed_no_time[,c(1:n)][,-h])
  m = ncol(summary_transposed_no_time)
  print(paste("added in a total columns for region", h, "so the column count is now : ",m))

} # end for (h in 1:nrow(filtered_data_contents)){
```